# jQuery Mask-Money not working MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in MVC5 with ASP.NET project, so I want to implement MaskMoney jQuery from there [Mask Money](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/)

First I download jquery File and I add to my bundle

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.maskMoney.js"
                  ));
```

So I call it in layout

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Finally in my view I call it using @script section at the end of my file:

```
   <script>
        $(function () {
        $('#Total').maskMoney();
    })
   </script>
```

And in my edit for I use id to identify it

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Total, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number",@id="Total", @min = "0", @Value="",  @required = "required" } })
```

but when I load page, nothing occurs, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Probably not related but start by removing all the html attributes except `@class = "form-control"` - the `id` is already `"Total"`, your should never override the `value` attribute and in MVC `required` should be handles by the `[Required]` attribute, and you do not want `type="number"` (you want the default textbox for the plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the script into a `document.ready` function:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Total').maskMoney();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is it placed after your `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`? And if you look at the F12 developer tools in the browser is the script being loaded without errors?

Comment: Can you see if you can reproduce the problem in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I try but it no works too . [jsfiddle-Mask-Money](https://jsfiddle.net/zp29jt6s/1/)

Comment: I've updated the JSFiddle to work, I had to paste the MaskMoney code in since it wasn't reading from GitHub. https://jsfiddle.net/zp29jt6s/4/ Doesn't help your initial question though. Make sure you're not getting any console errors.

Comment: Also, try making the input type `text` rather than number.

Comment: No I don't have any console errors :( and I try it to and no works

Comment: In that case I'm afraid I don't know why it's not working. Maybe try cutting down the properties you are giving it just in case there's a conflict like Stephen said in his comment.

Comment: OMG, I'm close... I think another jQuery I use is block maskmoneyQuery... because I do another view without layout, and It runs!. I comment tomorrow if I solve it!